# How to dash all but one line in plotly distplot?

Tags: python, plotly

I want to use plotly's distribution functions to emphasize the behavior of one variable relative to the others, so I want only this one to be a solid line while the rest are dashed. For instance, in this plotly example:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.randn(200) - 1
x2 = np.random.randn(200)
x3 = np.random.randn(200) + 1

hist_data = [x1, x2, x3]

group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
colors = ['#333F44', '#37AA9C', '#94F3E4']

# Create distplot with curve_type set to 'normal'
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, show_hist=False, colors=colors, show_rug =False)
fig.show()
```

Which results in
[image]

How do I make the lines of Group 2 and Group 3 dashed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update the traces and use selector for each one:

```
import plotly.figure_factory as ff
import numpy as np

x1 = np.random.randn(200) - 1
x2 = np.random.randn(200)
x3 = np.random.randn(200) + 1

hist_data = [x1, x2, x3]

group_labels = ['Group 1', 'Group 2', 'Group 3']
colors = ['#3344FF', '#FFFFFF', '#AF0000']

# Create distplot with curve_type set to 'normal'
fig = ff.create_distplot(hist_data, group_labels, show_hist=False, colors=colors, show_rug =False)

fig.update_traces(selector={"name": "Group 1"},
                  line={'dash': 'dash'}).update_traces(
                  selector={"name": "Group 3"},
                  line={'dash': 'dash'})

fig.show()
```

[image]